# Sonata Admin - The current field is not linked to an admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i ve got two classes : template and templateparameters.

Here is the code for the first one :

```
<?php

namespace HPI\DisplayBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Template
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="HPI_template")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Template
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="templatelabel", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $templatelabel;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="templatedescription", type="text")
     */
    private $templatedescription;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="templatefile", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $templatefile;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set templatelabel
     *
     * @param string $templatelabel
     * @return Template
     */
    public function setTemplatelabel($templatelabel)
    {
        $this->templatelabel = $templatelabel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get templatelabel
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTemplatelabel()
    {
        return $this->templatelabel;
    }

    /**
     * Set templatedescription
     *
     * @param string $templatedescription
     * @return Template
     */
    public function setTemplatedescription($templatedescription)
    {
        $this->templatedescription = $templatedescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get templatedescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTemplatedescription()
    {
        return $this->templatedescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set templatefile
     *
     * @param string $templatefile
     * @return Template
     */
    public function setTemplatefile($templatefile)
    {
        $this->templatefile = $templatefile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get templatefile
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTemplatefile()
    {
        return $this->templatefile;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->templatelabel;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the second one :

```
namespace HPI\DisplayBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TemplateParameters
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="HPI_templateparameters")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TemplateParameters
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parametername", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $parametername;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Template")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $template;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set parametername
     *
     * @param string $parametername
     * @return TemplateParameters
     */
    public function setParametername($parametername)
    {
        $this->parametername = $parametername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parametername
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getParametername()
    {
        return $this->parametername;
    }

    /**
     * Set template
     *
     * @param \HPI\DisplayBundle\Entity\Template $template
     * @return TemplateParameters
     */
    public function setTemplate(\HPI\DisplayBundle\Entity\Template $template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get template
     *
     * @return \HPI\DisplayBundle\Entity\Template 
     */
    public function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->template;
    }
}
```

As you can notice there is a manytoone relationships between theses 2 classes

I ve created a relevant service in my config.yml

```
sonata.admin.templateparameters:
    class: HPI\AdminBundle\Models\TemplateParametersAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Marketing", label: "Template Parameters" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - HPI\DisplayBundle\Entity\TemplateParameters
        - ~
```

When i want to add a new parameter in the sonata admin, using directly the templateparameters admin i've got no problem. But as soon as i want to add it as a collection in the template admin, i've got the following message : The current field `parametername` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``

So as i mentionned i'm sure that the admin is existing, cause i can use it by acting directly on it. Anyone got an idea ? i went through several topics here but it's not really clear to me how they solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and *resolved it by* creating admin for the field as you did for TemplateParametersAdmin and changing the $formMapper as following:

```
->add('sos', 'sonata_type_model',
    [
    'property' => 'title',
    'multiple' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'attr' => ['style' => 'width: 100%;']
    ]
)
```

The type 'sonata_type_model' actually makes a difference.